# Audio streaming in Android : what are my options?

Tags: java, android, streaming, sctp

I would like to build a Client/Server mobile application where the Server stream a list of audio files to all clients who are connected to it. I did some research on this topic and I have found that SCTP protocol could provide such functionality (i.e. Streaming). I am wondering though if there are any other better solutions in term of Scalability, Synchronization..., which are easy to implement and are well known within Android Developers Community. Many thanks.